# Как поставить PySide2 на Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu

Пытался поставить PySide2 по инструкции на сайте Qt. Собственно установился PySide2t и через него ничего не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста как поставить PySide2.

Comment: слова "ничего не работает" не слишком информативны: какие конкретно команды вы запускали, что конкретно в ответ получали. Чтобы людям с похожей проблемой было легче найти этот вопрос, добавьте как текст необходимую информацию [edit]

Answer (score 2):

Использовал pip, а нужно было использовать pip3.